# Binary pattern matching into list

Tags: elixir

I do this:

```
<<a :: big-size(16), b :: big-size(16), c :: big-size(16)>> = <<0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3>>
```

And then result will be:

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
```

But what I actually need is:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
```

Is there any way to achieve that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I read your comment in answer by greggreg correctly, this is one way of doing it:

```
<< size::8, rest::binary>> = <<3,0,25,1,1,2,1,6,4,3>>
<< data::size(size)-unit(16)-binary, rest::binary>> = rest
elements = for << <<element::16>> <- data>>, do: element

# At this point, elements is the list of n 16 bit integers
# (n being the first byte), and rest is the rest of the binary
```

Answer (score 5):

Not with pattern matching directly. You can only match on the whole structure or a sub structure. You can't coerce one structure into another.

One more line of code gets you there though:

```
<<a :: 16, b :: 16, c :: 16>> = <<0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3>>
a = [a, b, c] # a equals [1, 2, 3]
```

Or you could write a comprehension to do it:

```
a = for <<b :: 16 <-  <<0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3>> >>, do: b
```

Comment: Basically, I need to match binary into list of two-byte integers. But size of the list comes as first byte of this binary, so I need to do this somewhat more dynamic.

Comment: Well that's kind of a different question all together, but I'll give it a go.

Comment: @greggreg Sorry for hijacking. FWIW, I agree that the question in comment is a different question, and I think your answer should be accepted as the correct answer to the original question.

Comment: @sasajuric no worries!! I just like answering questions, I don't really care about the points. Plus I didn't know the `size(size)-unit(16)-binary` form existed and learned something!